# Getting “Cannot zoom to selected feature(s) : No extent could be determined” from PyQGIS

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, python-3

I am using QGIS 3.4.4.

I am trying to zoom on a specific place of my map using PyQGIS

In order to do so I've defined the layer I wanted to get the features :

```
couche_parcelles = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Parcelles')[0]
```

Then I defined the extent of my layer in order to zoom :

```
ext = couche_parcelles.extent()
xmin = ext.xMinimum()
xmax = ext.xMaximum()
ymin = ext.yMinimum()
ymax = ext.yMaximum()
zoomRectangle = QgsRectangle(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax)
```

Then I created the canvas in order to have a reference to my layer :

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.setExtent(zoomRectangle)
canvas.refresh()
```

Then I get the Id's I need to get the zoom on the specific point I'm aiming at :

```
identifiants_parcelles = [x['Idu'] for x in couche_parcelles.getFeatures()]
```

Finally, I write the block which is supposed to make me zoom on my section :

```
expr = "\"Id\"=36773"
selection = QgsExpression(expr)
vecteur = couche_parcelles.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(selection))
elemts = [x for x in vecteur]
couche_parcelles.selectByIds(elemts)
canvas.zoomToSelected(couche_parcelles)
canvas.refresh()
```

It did work once without the need to specify the extent of my layer but then I've had the same error : Cannot zoom to selected feature(s): No extend could be determined

and yet I did determine my extent here so I don't understand why QGIS doesn't perform the zoom on the Id I'm giving him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that I used:

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
couche_parcelles = project.mapLayersByName("(Layer's name)")[0]
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.setSelectionColor(QColor.fromRgb(255,255,0))

#select according to the "cadastre" unique id called "Idu"
expr = "\"Idu\"='(number of the selection)'"
selection = QgsExpression(expr)
it = couche_parcelles.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(selection))

ids = [i.id() for i in it]
couche_parcelles.selectByIds(ids)
canvas.zoomToSelected(couche_parcelles)
canvas.zoomScale(1500)
```